kdb/q How to join two tables based on two similar columns
I have a sales records table that looks like this:



Name
Item
Action
Price
Num_Items




Ann
Apple
Buy
5.00
10


Ann
Apple
Sell
6.00
12


Ann
Bread
Sell
9.00
9


Bob
Apple
Buy
5.00
14


Bob
Salt
Buy
1.00
10


Bob
Salt
Buy
1.00
1


Bob
Salt
Sell
2.00
2



sales_data: ([] Name: `Ann`Ann`Ann`Bob`Bob`Bob`Bob; Item: `Apple`Apple`Bread`Apple`Salt`Salt`Salt; Action: `Buy`Sell`Sell`Buy`Buy`Buy`Sell; Price: 5.00 6.00 9.00 5.00 1.00 1.00 2.00; Num_Items: 10 12 9 14 10 1 2)

The output is the Name-Item pairs that have >=1 Buys and Sells:



Name
Item




Ann
Apple


Bob
Salt



distinct_data: ([] Name: `Ann`Bob; Item: `Apple`Salt)

I would then like to add data to the distinct_data table based on the sales_data, like so:



Name
Item
Num_Buy
Num_Sold
Weighted_Avg_Price_Bought
Weighted_Avg_Price_Sold




Ann
Apple
10
12
5
6


Bob
Salt
11
2
1
2



How would I join the sales_data and distinct_data tables in order to do that? Would this be a case of an inner join?

Firstly you can generate the distinct data using a command similar to that Terry gave in your previous question, including all columns:
q)data:select from sales_data where({all`Buy`Sell in x};Action)fby([]Name;Item)
Name Item  Action Price Num_Items
---------------------------------
Ann  Apple Buy    5     10
Ann  Apple Sell   6     12
Bob  Salt  Buy    1     10
Bob  Salt  Buy    1     1
Bob  Salt  Sell   2     2


You can then aggregate the data as you wish:
q)agg:select sum Num_Items, Num_Items wavg Price by Name,Item,Action from data
Name Item  Action| Num_Items Price
-----------------| ---------------
Ann  Apple Buy   | 10        5
Ann  Apple Sell  | 12        6
Bob  Salt  Buy   | 11        1
Bob  Salt  Sell  | 2         2

And pivot to get the desired output. To keep this simple I will create 2 pivot tables.
q)P:`Num_Buy`NumSold
q)vol:`Name`Item`Num_Buy`Num_Sold xcol exec P#(Action!Num_Items) by Name,Item from agg
Name Item | Num_Buy Num_Sold
----------| ----------------
Ann  Apple| 10      12
Bob  Salt | 11      2

q)P:`Weighted_Avg_Price_Bought`Weighted_Avg_Price_Sold
q)wag:`Name`Item`Weighted_Avg_Price_Bought`Weighted_Avg_Price_Sold xcol exec P#(Action!Price) by Name,Item from agg
Name Item | Weighted_Avg_Price_Bought Weighted_Avg_Price_Sold
----------| -------------------------------------------------
Ann  Apple| 5                         6
Bob  Salt | 1                         2

And finally join them to give the desired output:
q)0!vol uj wag
Name Item  Num_Buy Num_Sold Weighted_Avg_Price_Bought Weighted_Avg_Price_Sold
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ann  Apple 10      12       5                         6
Bob  Salt  11      2        1                         2


I think you need to add the definition of P for completeness. It's the column names you want to use in the pivot. Num_BuyNumSold in the first case and Wighted_Avg_Price_BoughtWeighted_Avg_Price_Sold in the second
